# tar.gz extract all S3 using python

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I have got a `tar.gz` file which contains multiple `tsv` files in `s3` which needs to be extracted into another folder.

I used `tarfile` library in python and get passing `tar.gz` file s3 path as input but getting an error as `dict object has not attribute tell`.

Can any one help me on how to resolve that?

thanks,
Rj

Comment: Can you share the name of the library you used? Also, share the exact error.

Comment: import tarfile library. when i try to provide the absolute s3 path(s3://bucket/filename.tar.gz) i am getting an error as no such file exists. But when i try to get the s3 object and used             tar = tarfile.open(fileobj=lookupobj) i am getting the above error.

Comment: @Rjuser, please update your question with an example of the code you're referring to.. BTW, to open a file from S3, you'll need first to download the file and then extract it.